# Using gems in rails -- require 'gemname' results in No File Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I've been trying to use the 'twitter_oauth' gem with my rails application but whenever I have `require 'twitter_oauth'`, I get a "No such file to load" error.

I've already listed the twitter_oauth gem in my Gemfile, and when I try to initiate a new instance of Client in the rails console, it works perfectly fine, even when I don't first enter `require 'twitter_oauth'`. I even made a test ruby file where all it had was:

```
require 'twitter_oauth'

client = TwitterOAuth::Client.new
if client != nil
  puts "It worked!"
else
  puts "It did not work"
end
```

And running that file worked also.

I've tried putting require 'rubygems' also and I've tried placing the require 'twitter_oauth' code in the config/application.rb file.

Other gems work fine, such as 'will_paginate' (in my rails application, in rails console and in irb)

Also, interestingly enough, when I'm in irb, require 'twitter_oauth' results in an error too but when I run that simple ruby program, it works fine.

Comment: If you are using rvm, make sure that the correct ruby version and gemset is being used. Also check what gemset is being used in `.rvmrc` in the project, if there is such a file.

Comment: thanks for the reply  unfortunately, I am not using rvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just installed this gem and made a new rails 3 app, added it to the Gemfile and I can access it fine from 'rails console' and from within the app when running 'rails server' and also from 'irb'. Are you sure you've typed the gem name correctly? I confused myself by typing 'twitter_oath' a few times and not 'twitter_oauth'...

Have you got the latest rubygems? perhaps try:

```
$ sudo gem install rubygems-update
$ sudo gem update --system
$ sudo gem update
```

Are you using rails 3? What OS & ruby are you using?